# Crystal Report - Creating a default number of three digit

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a field where for different transactions I get numbers from database like 78, 781 or 7.81 but in the report I nee to show only 781 i.e. 3 digit only without decimal whatever is the number coming from database.

Comment: your question is confusing... if your output is 2 digit how would we know what is the 3rd digit? edit your question

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a formula field like this:

```
if (REPLACE(CSTR({yourField}), ".", "") LIKE "78*") then 781 else 0
```